# Como validar pelo menos um campo obrigatório?

Tags: php, laravel, validação, validator

Tenho dois campos CPF e CNPJ, o usuário deve digitar apenas um, mas nunca deixar os dois campos vazios. Desta forma ele deixa obrigatório os dois campos:

```
 [
   'Cpf' => array('required'),
   'Cnpj' => array('required'),
 ]
```

Existe alguma maneira no Laravel de validar apenas um campo obrigatório quando um estiver preenchido?

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel ?

Comment: Tenta assim: `'cpf' => 'required|required_without_all:cnpj', 'cnpj' => 'required|required_without_all:cpf',`

Comment: @Zooboomafoo VERSION = '5.1.45 (LTS)';

Comment: @Zooboomafoo Acho que não funciona para esta versão: Method [validateRequired|requiredWithoutAll] does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode-se usar o  **`required_without`** ou **`required_without_all`**.

```
[
    'Cpf'  => 'required_without:Cnpj',
    'Cnpj' => 'required_without:Cpf',
]
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou com o required_without

Comment: Chique dez! Documentação...